# Extract list from list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists in python3.

[image: entities]

I need a list of each inner list fields for : entity_id, formatted_address, name, type

There are 10 entity_id, formatted_address etc.. and I need a list of 10 for each field.

For entity_id I've tried:

`entity_id = list(map(lambda x: x['entity_id'], entities))`

But I get an exception : list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - always paste your code, **don't paste screenshots**.

With `x['entity_id']` you are not getting value from dictionary, but you are indexing a list. If your lists contain 1 element, then you can try:

```
entity_id = list(map(lambda x: list(x[0].items()), entities))
```

For example:

```
entities = [
    [{'ent': 'something', 'id': 'something_else'}], 
    [{'ent': 'foo', 'id': 'bar'}]
]
entity_id = list(map(lambda x: list(x[0].items()), entities))
>>> entity_id
[[('ent', 'something'), ('id', 'something_else')], [('ent', 'foo'), ('id', 'bar')]]
```

Map function takes every list, then it extracts the first element(index 0) and returns it's items (`dict.items()` function)

EDIT. I've added code which was asked in the comments:
Here you go:

```
>>> entity_id = list(map(lambda x: x[0]['id'], entities))
>>> entity_id
['something_else', 'bar']
```

Comment: I need entity_id to be ['something_else','bar'] from your example.  My list contains 10 lists of 4 items